# Am I wasting my time pulling dallisgrass seed pods before mowing?

Tags: weed-control, weeds, lawn-repair

My fescue lawn that is largely dormant right now because of the heat, but dallisgrass is thriving and driving me crazy.  I started pulling out by hand the tall seed pod stalks before mowing my yard, hoping to somewhat limit its ability to spread.  Here's an image of what I'm pulling up:

[image]

(Note: I originally identified this as crab grass, but upon adding this photo, I realized that I'm mostly dealing with dallisgrass, not crab grass.  I do have a small section of lawn that has some crab grass in it, but that plant is spread closer to the ground and has a Y-shaped seed stalk).

I understand its seeds primarily germinate in the spring time during cooler temperatures, so I wonder if I am just wasting my time by pulling out the seed pods?  Am I just being overly cautious, and doing this is no more effective than applying a pre-emergent treatment next spring?  Thank you!

Comment: In retrospect, I can probably just mow my lawn with the grass clipping bag attached to the mower, rather than use its mulching feature, as that should catch most of these seed pods.  The downside, of course, is that I lose the positives of mulching my lawn as I mow it.